# Enabling and disabling playback and recording devices

Tags: c#, audio, playback, recording, directsound

I am a newbie in c#..Please dont get annoyed by my question if its kinda silly one..

I need to see the disabled playback and recording devices by c# code and want to enable  or disable it as per my need.
How can I approach..??
I made a code using DirectX.DirectSound API but it is limited to enumerate the devices which are only enabled and i am not able see the disabled devices present. And I don't think there is any method of disabling or enabling the devices.

I'll be very thankful to u for the help.

And please also suggest me how can I do this with using other API's if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a really really old thread... but I landed here trying to find out how to list disabled audio devices, and I was successful with a C++ project called [AudioEndpointController](http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/)

Simply change the line:

```
PlaybackDevice = pEnum->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, &pDevices);
```

to:

```
PlaybackDevice = pEnum->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED, &pDevices);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, it is not possible to programatically enable/disable devices. As for the first part of your question (need to see disabled devices), this is in fact possible but not using c# alone, you'll have to use WASAPI for this either by using C++/CLI or using explicit PInvoke in C#. You're looking for IMMDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints which takes a flag indicating if you want to see disabled/unplugged etc. devices. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. The nice about WASAPI's IMMDevice interface in this case is that it exposes a GUID which corresponds to the device's DirectSound id, so you can actually use WASAPI to detect which devices are active/inactive etc. and do all your other stuff using DirectSound. For this, you'll want to use IMMDevice::OpenPropertyStore, and query for the PKEY_AudioEndpoint_GUID property. This is the exact same thing that's passed in to DirectSound's DSEnumCallback function.

Comment: Though microsoft doesnt allow it, but somehow I managed to do it via backdoor entry through registry edit. Thanks for replying anyways! Cheers!

Comment: @AmitArya, I also want to record system sound while recording desktop screen. I don't know how to do loopback recording how you managed this. could you please tell me?

Comment: @AmitArya  registry edit will need Administrator privileges? is there a different way?